# Remove string after dash IF end string matches given string

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is remove a string after the dash *if* the string after the dash matches what is appended.

For example it'd be like: if endofstring is equal to givenstring, remove dash and everything after, else keep the dash

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string='Hello this is the-end';
$remove='end';
$i=strrpos($string, $remove);
if ($i===strlen($string)-strlen($remove)) $string=substr($string, 0, $i-1);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: Seemed a lot harder than it was, but thanks! I'll accept this when I can :D